# No code completion of SCSS files in PhpStorm/WebStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

In `PhpStorm` while editing `ts` file I get no import code completion for files other than `ts`.

On screenshot below You can see no suggestion for valid `alerts.scss` file.

`template.ts` is visible in suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please vote for [WEB-26481](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26481) to be notified on any progress with it